# How to make Gravity Forms name field input only accept letters

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How do I make the gravity form name field only accept letters, numbers should give an error.

Comment: So you do not want any numbers in the name field and you want to show an error message if there are numbers ?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. The name field should only accept letters. "test123" for example would give an error saying "this field must only contain letters" (or something along those lines)

Comment: Only on first name and last name ?

Comment: I'm just using a single text input field for the name, so essentially the user can enter a full name if they wish, but if there's a letter anywhere, it will give the error

Comment: Thats mean you are not not using an actual name field which can found in advanced fields. Are you using single line text from gravity forms?

Comment: I tried using the name field and setting it to just the first name (default is first and last name", but I was still able to enter "test123" without an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221066/discussion-between-birdyoung-and-alwayshelping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [gform_field_validation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/#4-name-field-validation) validation filter to be able to do this kind of `validation` before the form submits.

In addition, we need to use [preg_match](https://www.google.com/search?q=preg_match&rlz=1C1CHZL_enAU805AU805&oq=preg_match&aqs=chrome..69i57.478j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) function of PHP with a `regex` to ensure we are only taking **Letters** from Full Name input value.

**Just add this code in your active theme functions.php file:** (Code tested and working)

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    if ( $field->type == 'name' ) {

        // Input values
        $fullName = rgar( $value, $field->id . '.3' );
         
        if ( empty( $fullName )) {
            $result['is_valid'] = false;
            $result['message']  = empty( $field->errorMessage ) ? __( 'This field is required. Please enter a complete name.', 'gravityforms' ) : $field->errorMessage;
        } else if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]/', $fullName)) { //check for letters only
            $result['is_valid'] = false;
            $result['message']  = empty( $field->errorMessage ) ? __( 'Full name must ony contains letters.', 'gravityforms' ) : $field->errorMessage;
        } else {
            $result['is_valid'] = true;
            $result['message']  = '';
        }
    }
    return $result; //return results
}, 10, 4 );
```